# Поиск определенного оптимизированного участка кода

Tags: c, ассемблер, оптимизация, gcc

Как найти в ассемблерном коде, получаемом через `gcc -S`, участок кода, относящийся к определенному кода языка Си.
Например, в файле на Си был код:

```
for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    ivector5[ i * 2 + 3 ] = 5;
```

И нужно найти его аналог в ассемблерных командах, созданных gcc.

Возможно ли поставить какую-либо метку до и после начала этого участка кода, чтобы его можно было бы найти в оптимизированном ассемблерном коде?

UPD
Скомпилировал, как подсказали в комментариях.
Увидел это:

```
 185 011a 89050000      movl    %eax, i5(%rip)
 185      0000
 186 0120 B9000000      movl    $ivector5+12, %ecx
 186      00
 187 0125 BE000000      movl    $ivector5+812, %esi
 187      00
 188 012a 660F1F44      .p2align 4,,10
 188      0000
 189                    .p2align 3
 190                .L7:
 126:optbench.c    **** 
 191                    .loc 1 126 0 discriminator 3
 192 0130 C7010500      movl    $5, (%rcx)
 192      0000
 193 0136 4883C108      addq    $8, %rcx
 125:optbench.c    ****                 ivector5[ i * 2 + 3 ] = 5;
 194                    .loc 1 125 0 discriminator 3
 195 013a 4839CE        cmpq    %rcx, %rsi
 196 013d 75F1          jne .L7
```

Я так понимаю, что вставки кода Си, говорят, что происходило во время создания ассемблерного кода (как бы бок о бок).

Comment: `gcc -Wa,-adhln -g source_code.c > assembly_list.s` взято отсюда https://www.systutorials.com/240/generate-a-mixed-source-and-assembly-listing-using-gcc/

Comment: @Mike,а как можно тогда такую команду дополнить gcc -S -O2 -o test.s  optbench.c

Comment: почему именно дополнить ? `gcc -O2 -Wa,-adhln -g  optbench.c >test.s`

Comment: @Mike, а как тогда я увижу , где именно этот массив ivector5 используется, метки появятся ?

Comment: а вы просто выполните и посмотрите. так обычно гораздо быстрее чем спрашивать и ожидать ответа. я вот лично выполнил и увидел внутри asm кода полный исходный C-код, никакие метки не нужны

Comment: @Mike,наверное, лучше будет в вопрос записать, что у мня вышло

Comment: Ну как бы да. листинг говорит сам за себя. Вместо переменной i используется rcx как текущее смещение и в rsi сразу загружается адрес последнего элемента массива `(100*2+3)*sizeof(int)=812` и дальше записывает 5 в цикле пока не достигнет последнего адреса

Comment: @Mike, я правильно понял, что это мне даёт ассемблерный код, соответствующий Сишному, как бы параллельно и то и другое?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: @Mike,а что это означает `.loc 1 135 0`

Comment: Идите сюда: https://gcc.godbolt.org/ и наберите сишный код в левую колонку, справа будет ассемблерный код, красиво раскрашенный в соответствии с сишными строками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесу свою "лепту".

Видите ли, если вы будете ограничиваться тем ассемблерным кодом, который занимается только обработкой цикла, то вряд ли вы полностью поймёте, как это работает, потому что за этими "рамками" стоят тоже какие-то преобразования, которые применяются в т.н."цикловом" блоке кода.

Возьмём в пример вот эту программу :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 203

int main ()
{
    size_t counter = 0;

    int* buffer = malloc( BUF_SIZE * sizeof(int) );

    if ( NULL == buffer ) return -1;

    for ( counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++ )
        buffer[ counter * 2 + 3 ] = 5;

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Я запустил `gcc` с единственным флагом , `-ansi`.
Посмотрев и проанализровав бинарный файл через `gdb`, видим следующий ассемблерный код ( пользуюсь "GNU/Linux" + показываю на `intel` - синтаксисе ) :

```
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
sub    rsp,0x10
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
mov    edi,0x32c
call   0x1040 <malloc@plt>
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0
jne    0x555555555171                                     
mov    eax,0xffffffff                   
jmp    0x5555555551b1                    
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0                          
jmp    0x555555555199   
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]  
shl    rax,0x3                         
lea    rdx,[rax+0xc]                  
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]       
add    rax,rdx                        
mov    DWORD PTR [rax],0x5            
add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1        
cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x63 
jbe    0x55555555517b
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]              
mov    rdi,rax                               
call   0x555555555030 <free@plt>             
mov    eax,0x0
leave
ret
```

Давайте потихоньку разбираться (если что-то не так написал - поправляйте :D ) :

```
; монтирование стекового кадра
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
sub    rsp,0x10

; здесь просто инициализация
; size_t counter = 0
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0

; "0x32c" в десятеричном виде есть следующее :
; BUF_SIZE * sizeof(int) = 203 * 4 = 812 байт
; помещаем это в регистр для аргумента функции "malloc"
mov    edi,0x32c

; выделяем память с размером, указанным в регистре "edi"
call   0x1040 <malloc@plt>

; сохраняем результат, который возвращает malloc
; ( там теперь либо NULL, либо адрес, с которого начинается выделенный блок памяти )
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax

; проверяем, NULL или нет
cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],0x0

; если не NULL, то "прыгаем" к основному блоку команд
; а иначе просто продолжаем работу.
jne    0x555555555171 ----------------------
                                           |
; заносим в код возврарата значение "-1"   |
; и "прыгаем" в конец                      |
mov    eax,0xffffffff                      |
jmp    0x5555555551b1 ---------------------|-----
                                           |    |
; counter = 0                              |    |
mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0 <------------    |
                                                |  
jmp    0x555555555199 ------------------        |
                                       |        |
; выполнение цикла начинается здесь    |        |
; в rax теперь счётчик цикла           |        |
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8] <-------|---     |
                                       |  |     | 
; здесь хитро определяем индекс        |  |     |
; (первые индексы - 0, 3, 5, 7, 9 ...) |  |     |
; смещаем rax на 3 разряда влево       |  |     |
; т.е. умножаем на 8;                  |  |     |
shl    rax,0x3                         |  |     |
                                       |  |     | 
; прибавляем 12 (т.е + 3 элемента)     |  |     |
; и заносим в rdx                      |  |     |
lea    rdx,[rax+0xc]                   |  |     |
                                       |  |     |
; помещаем в rax адрес массива         |  |     |
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]        |  |     |
                                       |  |     |
; прибавляем к адресу количество байт  |  |     |
; (т.е определяем индекс)              |  |     |
; (напоминаю, что 1 адрес - 1 байт)    |  |     |
add    rax,rdx                         |  |     |
                                       |  |     |
; теперь в rax - нужный адрес, т.е.    |  |     |
; buffer[ counter * 2 + 3 ]            |  |     |
; присваиваем 5                        |  |     |
mov    DWORD PTR [rax],0x5             |  |     |
                                       |  |     |
; counter++                            |  |     |
add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x1         |  |     |
                                       |  |     |
; counter <= 99?                       |  |     |
cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x63 <-------  |     |
; если да, то продолжаем цикл             |     |
jbe    0x55555555517b  --------------------     |
                                                |
; перемещаем адрес массива в rax                |
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]                 |
; помещаем адрес в регистр для аргумента        |
mov    rdi,rax                                  |
; освобождаем память                            |
call   0x555555555030 <free@plt>                |
                                                |
; успешный код возврата                         |
mov    eax,0x0                                  |
                                                |
; демонтирование стекового кадра                |
leave   <----------------------------------------
ret
```

Теперь вам, надеюсь, понятно, что ,сразу заглянув в цикл, не всегда можно будет определить, с какими адресами мы работаем.

А вообще, в утилите `gdb` можно ставить `breakpoint`'ы, но сразу же оказавшись там,я бы на вашем месте "заблудился".